# Create a default python interpreter settings for PyCharm on non persistent virtual machines in Microsoft remote desktop services (RDS Environment)

Tags: python, pycharm

Is there a way to setup a default Python interpreter for all PyCharm projects on non persistent VMs (MS RDS)?

Scenario: Administrator can create a Python interpreter settings on his Master machine and distributes it to VM users where user gets different VM every time (non-persistent) while log in.

PyCharm application in user's VM always asks for interpreter settings where user cannot spend time to create interpreter settings every time on log in.

Is there any configurations to make default Python interpreter settings for User non persistent VMs?

Comment: Is interpreter located in some widely used place? E.g. `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39` or `PROJECT_DIR\.venv`?

Comment: I created a location for Interpreter  under user profile, E.g.C:\Users\Softwares\python37\Python.exe

Comment: Is it listed in the windows registry under the keys specified in https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0514/?